# How to create a tip dialog box in Android?

Tags: android, tooltip

I'm looking for example of a tip dialog box with a arrow to point to a view. I try to use a QuickAction (https://github.com/alhneiti/Android-QuickAction/) modified to start on Activity initialize, but the show method of all QuickActions examples I get needs a click action to start because the have a method like this:

```
public void show(View anchor){
  ...
  showAtLocation(anchor, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, mPopupY);
}
```

I find a image of example:

[image: example]

Any help?

Comment: So when do you want to show these popups ?? I guess, when the activity starts, and after that they should disappear automatically after sometime. Something like...??

Comment: It´s a help for first time on Activity, after user click in popup or the view that arrow is pointed, it will disappear .

Comment: can we pass the view manually, and try to inflate the popup by calling show() method on start of the activity ?? Just an idea.

Comment: it does not work, because the view when is passed manually don´t get some values like it´s early to use getLocationOnScreen() return zeros at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a serach about getLocationOnScreen() I change my code to invoke quickaction show method like this:

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

      super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

      if(hasFocus) 
         quickAction.show(myView);
```

}